# How to work with Randoop on eclipse maven project?

Tags: maven, eclipse-plugin, randoop

I am trying to use Randoop to genrate automatic test cases for my project but I could not get details about how to add randoop in eclipse.

https://randoop.github.io/randoop/manual/index.html has information about command line usage. I would like to work on Randoop with Maven project on eclipse.

Comment: You gave a link to the manual, and the manual has a section about Maven: https://randoop.github.io/randoop/manual/index.html#maven-plugin

Comment: @mernst Thanks for your reply. Yeah, I tried that. I added the plugin in pom.xml and run as maven test but It did not create any test cases.  I am looking for little bit more detailed document or video.

Comment: That's good to know.  In the future, please provide full information when you ask a question.